How can I repair Power BI Key data type?
I have a Power BI dashboard which has one Excel as a data source. I accidentally introduced a text data type in a date data type cell, so the Power BI stop refreshing since then. I have deleted the rows where the data were introduced and now the Power BI still cant refresh.
The message I keep receiving from Power BI is :
Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.. Key = [Id = "ebdc0fe6-72e7-452c-9f55-424e044acadc"]. Table = #table({"odata.type", "odata.id", "odata.etag", "odata.editLink", "Items@odata.navigationLinkUrl", "Id", "Title", "Items", "IsLeaf", "ItemKind", "ItemName"}, {}). ;The key didn't match any rows in the table.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: KPI Targets.
I don't know how to proceed in order to correct my Power BI :( Any advices?
I tried changing the data type in that cell so it match with the Power BI data type but the Error message keeps repeating. I also tried deleting the entire rows where the problem was but it does not change the Error.
I guess that the Power BI data has changed from date type to text type so now my problem is no more in the Excel but in the Power BI configuration.

From memory check to ensure that you have not included any duplicate keys in the table during the last refresh.
